# Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, html

I know the meaning of the problem, but I don't know how to solve it. This code is before the body tag :

```
<script>
var fileInput = document.getElementById('#fileToUpload');

    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() 
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener('load', function() 
        {
            alert('Contenu du fichier "' + fileInput.files[0].name + '" :\n\n' + reader.result);
        }, false);

        reader.readAsText(fileInput.files[0]);

    }, false);
</script>
```

Followed by this:

```
<body>
(...)
<input class="inputToCover" id="fileToUpload" type="file" multiple />
(...)
</body>
```

IE10 throw me this error : Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference, to the line : `fileInput.addEventListener('change', function()`.

**EDIT**

Actually thanks for the answer! I fixed it, now being `var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileToUpload');`, but the same error is still here. Any ideas?

Comment: id is `fileToUpload` not `#fileToUpload`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to eat your pizza before you actually make it.

You can not reference an element before it is rendered to the page. You need to either call your script [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload), on [document ready](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), or place it after the element on the page. Typically people place the scripts right before the closing body tag.